# Copy and paste only modified files while taking backup of old files in destination

Tags: git, shell, unix, command-line

I have a number of files that are present in one zip folder. The zip file contains folders and these folders contains files as well. The files are result of this command:

```
git archive --output=deploy.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB)
```

This means that the zip folder contains only the files that are changed between the commits HEAD and HEAD~1.

What I want to do is copy and paste the files and folders into one destination. The destination also contains multiple folders and files. I want to replace only the modified files and take backup of the replaced files. Simple usage of `cp` command is not working since it will replace the entire folder with only the changed file. i.e If the zipped folder contains a file `/config/configuration.xml` and the destination contains `/config/` n number of files, if I use a simple copy and paste the config folder itself will be replaced with only one file. Please note that the zipped folder, deploy.zip, contains multiple files like this.
Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: the 7z command can handle zip archives, `man 7z` and follow the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

I unzipped the zipped file into a temporary folder. Then I used the command :- cp -a  . This copied and replaced only the changed files while preserving the other files.

Regards,

-Ban